# DNA seq cutting using Linux

Tags: linux

I need to use the cut command on a human insulin sequence row wise but i don't know the command.I already ran byte wise command but the gave me column wise results. I cant use the -f option since i need to use a delimiter with it and the seq does not have any delimiters.
please answer asap

Comment: Could you please show the commands you tried so far and how the result should looks like? If you could give a simple example of how your data, it would be a good help to understand your problem.

Comment: `cut` is a linux command, but might not do what you intend. Could you please describe your problem with greater clarity?

Comment: I have an assignment where i have to use Linux commands on a bioinformatics problem i choose  to cut sort and uniq the sequence. however the cut command worked for byte wise cutting but not field wise since fields dont exist in a seq. also can someone tell me why do we sort a seq because wouldn't that result in a mutation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use either generic *NIX `cut` (you do not need a delimiter if you use `-c` option) or `head` tools. Even better, use any of a number of bioinformatics tools for sequence manipulation, such as EMBOSS `extractseq`.

**EXAMPLES:**

```
# Write into file output.txt characters 1-20 from each line of file input.txt:
cut -c1-20 input.txt > output.txt

# Write the first 5 lines of input.txt:
head -n5 input.txt > output.txt

# It is easier if you have your sequence in fasta format.
# Write characters 1..20 and 100-110 from input.fasta to output.fasta:
extractseq input.fasta output.fasta -regions "1-20 100-110"
```

---

One of the easy ways to install EMBOSS suite is using `conda` (from bioconda channel).

**SEE ALSO:**

EMBOSS `extractseq` help: https://www.bioinformatics.nl/cgi-bin/emboss/help/extractseq